# Anchor links work on Safari and Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html

I am working on a website and have created anchor links which work on Safari and Chrome but don't on Firefox. Can someone help me please?

this is the button:

```
<button class="_button _button-2"><a href="#tapanwork">WORK</a></button>
```

and this is where the link points to:

```
<a name="tapanwork"></a>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For Anchor link use <a href="(Your link here)">Work</a> and check.

Comment: please post more code

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, in my test at least, the button's behavior is superceding the link -- so the fact that the link is wrapped up in a button is preventing the anchor link from firing.  If you remove the button, you should find that the anchor link works fine within Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `"button"` and `"href"` both tags for link, Simply use below code its may help you out.

```
<a href="#tapanwork" class="_button _button-2">WORK</a>
```